# Remote WebDriver ignore certificate errors for Chrome

Tags: ruby, certificate, webdriver

How ignore sertificate with Remote WebDriver for Chrome? I try run this code:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'selenium-webdriver'
include Selenium

capabilities = WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:native_events => true)
driver = WebDriver.for(:remote,
                       :desired_capabilities => capabilities,
                       :url => "http://192.168.1.44:4444/wd/hub",
                       :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors]
                       )
driver.navigate.to "https://trunk.plus1.oemtest.ru/"
puts driver.title
driver.close
```

And get an error message:

```
home/igor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@selenium/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.12.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:51:in `initialize': unknown option: {:switches=>["--ignore-certificate-errors"]} (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach described above is not supported by latest chromedriver anymore. According to [this doc](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) chromeOptions should be used instead:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--ignore-certificate-errors" ]})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: caps
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chrome.switches'] = %w[--ignore-certificate-errors]

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like now the correct way of requesting insecure certs is setting [`accept_insecure_certs = true`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/capabilities.rb#L35) on the `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities` instance.